# <ArrayInput> with <SimpleFormIterator> of React Admin generate wrong output

Tags: react-admin

For the following:

```
<ArrayInput source="slotCaps" label="Schedule Caps">
    <SimpleFormIterator>
        <Box display="flex">
            <Box mr="0.5em">
                <NumberInput source="cap" step={1}/>
            </Box>
            <Box ml="0.5em">
                <SelectInput
                    source="period"
                    choices={[
                        {id: "0", name: "Day"},
                        {id: "1", name: "Week"},
                        {id: "2", name: "Month"}
                    ]}
                />
            </Box>
        </Box>
    </SimpleFormIterator>
</ArrayInput>
```

I get:

```
{
    "name": "test 5",
    "description": "test 5",
    "slotCaps": [
        {},
        {}
    ],
    "cap": 1,
    "period": "0"
}
```

I was expecting:

```
{
    "name": "test 5",
    "description": "test 5",
    "slotCaps": [
        {"cap": 1, "period": "0"},
    ],
}
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Could someone please explain what I have to change to obtain the second variant?
Thank you.

**Edit**

Not sure why but for some reason this works:

```
<ArrayInput source="slotCaps" label="Schedule Caps">
    <SimpleFormIterator>
        <NumberInput source="cap" step={1}/>
            <SelectInput
                source="period"
                choices={[
                    {id: 1, name: "Day"},
                    {id: 2, name: "Week"},
                    {id: 3, name: "Month"}
                ]}
                optionValue={"name"}
            />
    </SimpleFormIterator>
</ArrayInput>
```

If anyone knows how to make the first variant work please provide your input. I need the fields to be formatted properly and it looks like using the Box element is the best way to achieve that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

*Input* components must be the first-level children of *SimpleFormIterator*, not nested ones.

If you wish to use nested *Input* components, which is useful for displaying the form properly with material-ui *Box* elements, you need to use a *FormDataConsumer*, like below:

```
    <ArrayInput source="slotCaps" label="Schedule Caps">
      <SimpleFormIterator>
        <FormDataConsumer>
          {({ getSource, scopedFormData }) => {
            return (
              <Box display="flex">
                <Box mr="0.5em">
                  <NumberInput
                    source={getSource("cap")}
                    record={scopedFormData}
                    step={1}
                  />
                </Box>
                <Box ml="0.5em">
                  <SelectInput
                    source={getSource("period")}
                    record={scopedFormData}
                    choices={[
                      { id: "0", name: "Day" },
                      { id: "1", name: "Week" },
                      { id: "2", name: "Month" },
                    ]}
                  />
                </Box>
              </Box>
            );
          }}
        </FormDataConsumer>
      </SimpleFormIterator>
    </ArrayInput>
```

Then, for each *Input* component, all you need to do is add *getSource* in the source prop and *scopedFormData* to the record prop.

Answer (score 0):

remove source from NumberInput and SelectInput